# Why are these C macros not written as functions?

Tags: c, networking, coding-style, macros

I'm studying the code of the netstat tool (Linux), which AFAIK mostly reads a `/proc/net/tcp` file and dowa pretty-printing out of it.  (My focus is on the -t mode right now.)

I'm a bit puzzled by the coding style the authors have chosen:

```
static int tcp_info(void)
{
    INFO_GUTS6(_PATH_PROCNET_TCP, _PATH_PROCNET_TCP6, "AF INET (tcp)", tcp_do_one);
}
```

where

```
#define INFO_GUTS6(file,file6,name,proc)                \
 char buffer[8192];                                     \
 int rc = 0;                                            \
 int lnr = 0;                                           \
 if (!flag_arg || flag_inet) {                          \
    INFO_GUTS1(file,name,proc)                          \
 }                                                      \
 if (!flag_arg || flag_inet6) {                         \
    INFO_GUTS2(file6,proc)                              \
 }                                                      \
 INFO_GUTS3
```

where

```
 #define INFO_GUTS3                                      \
  return rc;
```

and

```
#if HAVE_AFINET6
#define INFO_GUTS2(file,proc)                           \
   lnr = 0;                                              \
   procinfo = fopen((file), "r");                        \
   if (procinfo != NULL) {                               \
     do {                                                \
       if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), procinfo))      \
          (proc)(lnr++, buffer);                          \
     } while (!feof(procinfo));                          \
     fclose(procinfo);                                   \
   }
#else
#define INFO_GUTS2(file,proc)
#endif
```

etc.

Clearly, my coding sense is tilting and says "those should be functions". I don't see any benefit those macros bring here. It kills readability, etc.

Is anybody around familiar with this code, can shed some light on what "INFO_GUTS" is about here and whether there could have been (or still has) a reason for such an odd coding style?

In case you're curious about their use, the full dependency graph goes like this:

```
#               /--->   INFO_GUTS1  <---\    
#  INFO_GUTS --*        INFO_GUTS2  <----*---- INFO_GUTS6
#      î        \--->   INFO_GUTS3  <---/           î 
#      |                                            |
# unix_info()              igmp_info(), tcp_info(), udp_info(), raw_info()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads as someones terrible idea to implement optional IPv6 support.  You would have to walk through the history to confirm, but the archive only seems to go back to 1.46 and the implied damage is at 1.20+.

I found a git archive going back to 1.24 and it is still there.  Older code looks doubtful.

Neither BusyBox or BSD code includes such messy code.  So it appeared in the Linux version and suffered major bit rot.

Comment: Quick-and-dirty modification by using #define instead of copy-paste. Okay, I think I see why things ended up that way, now.

Answer (score 3):

Your sense that "those macros should be functions" seems correct to me; I'd prefer to see them as functions.

It would be interesting to know how often the macros are used.  However, the more they're used, the more there should be a space saving if they're a real function instead of a macro.  The macros are quite big and use (inherently slow) I/O functions themselves, so there isn't going to be a speed-up from using the macro.

And these days, if you want inline substitution of functions, you can use `inline` functions in C (as well as in C++).

---

You can also argue that INFO_GUTS2 should be using a straight-forward `while` loop instead of the `do ... while` loop; it would only need to check for EOF once if it was:

```
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), procinfo))
    (*proc)(lnr++, buffer);
```

As it is, if there is an error (as opposed to EOF) on the channel, the code would probably go into an infinite loop; the `fgets()` would fail, but the `feof()` would return false (because it hasn't reached EOF; it has encountered an error - see `ferror()`), and so the loop would continue.  Not a particularly plausible problem; if the file opens, you will seldom get an error.  But a possible problem.

Comment: the do...while is something I don't get surprised of. To answer your other question, see dependency graph in the updated question.

Comment: Most modern compilers treat inline as a hint rather than a requirement, so tagging a function as inline makes no guarantees that it will in fact be inlined.

Comment: In the actual code, the macros are used exactly once.  The INFO_GUTS2() macro is conditionally defined, but the whole function could be written without the macro without any obvious deleterious effect.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason why. The person who wrote the code was likely very confused about code optimizations in general, and the concept of inlining in particular. Since the compiler is most likely GCC, there are several ways to achieve function inlining, if inlining was even necessary for this function, which I very much doubt.

Inlining a function containing file I/O calls would be the same thing as shaving an elephant to reduce its weight...

Answer (score 0):

Macros generate code: when it is called, the whole macro definition is expanded at the place of the call. If say, INFO_GUTS6 were a function, it wouldn't be able to declare, e.g., the buffer variable which would subsequently be usable by the code that follows the macro invocation. The example you pasted is actually very neat :-)